# No boot media detected after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I'm new to Linux. I have an old laptop that is too slow for Win10. I made a bootable USB stick following the instructions on Ubuntu desktop's home page. The laptop was previously dual-booted with Win10 and Lubuntu. It has a SATA and an M.2, both 1TB. I wanted to install Linux on the M.2 because that's faster. I booted into Try Ubuntu and formatted both drives to get rid of the Windows and the old Lubuntu (of course I wrote down the Windows license code).

The installation process seemed completely fine, I didn't get any error messages, but after it prompted me to remove the installation media and reboot the BIOS didn't detect any OS. I read in a post on this forum that I should try disabling the Legacy boot mode in the BIOS (I have no idea what boot mode is) but after that it didn't even see the bootable USB. What did I do wrong?

Yes, I tried installing again.

The laptop in question is a 10 year old HP ZBook 14.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. There's very little useful information, but here's my guess: Your BIOS Boot order is SATA, then M.2, and one of the now empty partitions on SATA has the "BOOT" flag set, but has nothing. Boot your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode, and use `gparted` to clear the flag on SATA. Take care, `gparted` is a powerful, dangerous tool. Be sure you are operating on the correct (SATA) disk.

Comment: Have ;you updated UEFI to latest firmware from HP and firmware for M.2 SSD? How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Many older HPs seem to be hardcoded to default boot "Windows Boot Manager" as UEFI description, but do not check actual boot file. Work around was a new entry with Windows description that boots Ubuntu. Similar? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: When I set the boot mode to Native UEFI it seems like BIOS doesn't see the USB even if I told Rufus to format it for UEFI. If I set boot mode to Legacy, install from USB and then switch to Native UEFI I can see Ubuntu in the manual boot drive select menu but not in the Boot order menu.